# mysql.connector not allowing me to upload gzip compressed data to database

Tags: python, c#, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to compress a file in Python, upload this data to a MySQL database and then download/decompress in C#. This is the how I am compressing the file:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from io  import BytesIO

def gzip_str(data):
   sio = BytesIO()
   with GzipFile(fileobj=sio, mode='wb') as gzip:
       gzip.write(data)

       return sio.getvalue()
```

And then the file is uploaded to the database doing something similar to:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

cnx = mysql.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

data = gzip_str( open("filepath.csv", "rb").read() )

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES (%s)", (data))
cnx.commit()
```

I get the error message `DatabaseError: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '8B0800'`. The header for compressed gzip data starts with `\x8b\x08\x00&` so it seems like this isn't recognized as a valid utf8mb4 character. Is there a way to work around this? I need this header intact in order to for it to decompress properly. The column `data` has the type `LONGBLOB` so I'm not even sure why it needs to be encoded anyway, shouldn't I just be storing byte data?

Comment: GZIP is ASCII so why are you reading file as binary "rb"?

Comment: @jdweng When just use `r` I get the error `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` when calling `gzip.write(data)`

Comment: @jdweng I cast it to a byte array using `bytes( open("filepath.csv", 'r').read(), 'utf8' )` and still get the same error as in the original question

Comment: How is field in database defined?

Comment: @jdweng `data LONGBLOB`

Comment: What is the size of your upload?  What is the size of the BLOB?  See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html